# What's the difference between the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home`, `/dev/VolGroup/lv_home`, and the `/home`?

Tags: linux, centos

What's the the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home`, `/dev/VolGroup/lv_home`, and the `/home`?

and what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev` entries are (links to) the block device itself; the `/home` directory is the directory which serves as the mount point for this filesystem so that userspace (applications) can access the contents stored on the block device.

The two `/dev` entries happen to be symbolic links to the real "device manager" device, which is something like `/dev/dm-2`. The LVM system creates the symbolic links to that `/dev/dm-2` so that it is easier to recognize what the device is. The links will look something like:

```
$ ls -l /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv-home /dev/VolGroup/lv-home
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jan 18 12:39 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv-home -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jan 18 12:39 /dev/VolGroup/lv-home -> ../dm-2
```

Your output will probably be slightly different.

Comment: there have the `/dev/VolGroup/lv-home` why there still need the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv-home`?

Comment: The device-mapper creates /dev/mapper/ entries and they should remain there.  They're probably referred to in /etc/fstab and are created automatically.  The /dev/VolGroup/ links are created for LVM volumes automatically to make life easier for people, and can also be used in fstab and other storage entries.